# GM_addStyle not working

Tags: css, greasemonkey

I am trying to make this very simple script to replace the header on google:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Hell yeah
// @description    HELL YEAH
// @include        http://www.google.*
// ==/UserScript==
GM_addStyle("div #logo {background-image: url('http://img220.imageshack.us/img220/5676/1251559315224.jpg') !important}");
```

But when I try to use it nothing happens. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

This is what I needed:

```
document.getElementById('logo').src = 'http://img220.imageshack.us/img220/5676/1251559315224.jpg';
```

Although there appears to be something odd with the image appearing on google

Answer (score 18):

I think you should add this:

```
 // @grant    GM_addStyle
```

Comment: and also remove //@grant none

Comment: I had not removed the `//@grant none`. Thanks for reminding.

Comment: Why do we have to grant everything... why is it not granted by default?!